# Set Selected Option Dynamically Using Angular 2+

Tags: angular, html

I'm creating a `<select>` dropdown using HTML5 and angular. I need the selected `<option>` to be determined dynamically via angular. If this were to be a static dropdown, it could be done as such:

```
<select>
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

A typical dynamic value could be determined as such (assuming `val1` and `val2` are declared in the component):

```
<select>
  <option [value]="val1">1</option>
  <option [value]="val2">2</option>
</select>
```

But given that the `select` attribute has no `=""` at the end, how could one assign it dynamically? In general, how could one assign such a value in angular? Especially since even if a value is provided to `selected`, it's simply ignored. So for example, `<option selected="false">` would be rendered the same as `<option selected>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured this one out on my own. The answer turns out to be pretty simple.

(assume that `value` is declared in the component)

```
<select>
  <option value="1" [selected]="value == 1">1</option>
  <option value="2" [selected]="value == 2">2</option>
</select>
```

I didn't think this would work, since in plain HTML `selected="false"` would still render the same as `selected`. However, it makes sense if you think about it. Adding the [] brackets tells angular to compute the value at compile time. And if the value is falesy, it will simply never make it into the DOM! So from HTML's perspective, `<option value="myValue" [selected]="false">` will translate as `<option value="myValue">`.